# How to set up static const variables inside templated classes?

Tags: c++, templates, static, constants

I have the following code:

```
template<typename flow_t, typename cost_t>
struct min_cost_flow {
    static const flow_t FLOW_INF = numeric_limits<flow_t>::max() / 2;
    static const cost_t COST_INF = numeric_limits<cost_t>::max() / 2;
    ...
};
```

Unfortunately it does not compile and gives the error "[...] undefined reference to `min_cost_flow::COST_INF".

Two fixes I've tried that I don't like include changing `const` to `constexpr` (successfully compiles on my machine, but not on another with an older version of gcc), and defining the value of the constants below the class, but this separates the values too far from where I want to use them. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not related to templates, `static`s have to be defined outside the class unless they're `inline` (which your old gcc probably doesn't support). Do your constants have to be static? Making them non-static would solve the problem

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Making them non-static would bloat the storage used for every instance of the class.

Comment: On older gcc, try compiling with `-std=c++11` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn them into member functions instead:

```
template<typename flow_t, typename cost_t>
struct min_cost_flow {
    static const flow_t FLOW_INF() { return numeric_limits<flow_t>::max() / 2; }
    static const cost_t COST_INF() { return numeric_limits<cost_t>::max() / 2; }
};
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, use `const` instead of `constexpr`.